# Xcode project crashes after .png file is added

Tags: xcode

I am building a simple Swift based project in Xcode 9.2.  I would like to import a .png image file into my project, to display within my app.  I attempt to do this by dragging a .png file into the Xcode Navigator.  A dialog box appears, asking me to "Choose options for adding these files:".  I select the "Copy items if needed" box, I select the "Create groups" radio button, and then I press "Finish".

The .png file now appears in my project, however my project no longer builds.  Instead of "Build Succeeded", I get "Build Failed".  The only change is adding the .png file.

The "Build Failed" message says that I have a "Code Sign Error".  Clicking on this message, I get the following additional detail:
Debug/FourBarVisualizer.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Deleting the .png file fixes the problem.

Adding .txt files or .jpg files the same way doesn't cause any problems.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.  I'd prefer not to have to convert all my .png files to .jpg.  Am I doing something wrong, or is this an Xcode bug?  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the png-file is incorrect/corrupt, but unlikely. If you have imagemagick installed you can use the program "identify" to make a basic check on the file, ie. "identify png-file".

Comment: Thanks Kometen.  Indeed there was some problem with this particular png file.  Odd, because the file displayed fine in Preview, and even within Xcode- I only got an error when I tried to build the project.  I generated a new version of this file (using Photoshop) with slightly different settings, and everything works again.  Thanks.

Comment: Good to hear.  :-) Finder (and xcode) appears to be more tolerant when displaying files then.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be certain this applies in your case, but I just suffered the identical problem and was all ready to blame the recent Xcode 9.3 update, but StackOverflow suggested your question as being similar to the one I was in the process of writing.

I was just about to use ImageMagick to convert the PNG to another PNG in the hope of removing whatever upsets Xcode and I noticed that it had the `hide extension` attribute set. Unchecking that (before adding to the project) fixes things for me.

Having discovered that, I can now see what the additional text in the error was getting at (`"resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed"`), even if it wasn't quite enough to guide me immediately to the solution.